# Descriptive statistics (frequencies, counts, proportions) after multiple imputation

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics, multiple-imputation

I recently ran a multiple imputation using the *mice* package in R to generated imputed datasets. I have no problems with running inferential statistics on the pooled data (logistic and Cox regressions) and generating pooled odds/Hazard ratios and confidence intervals. However, I do have a question regarding the report of descriptive statistics (counts, proportions, frequencies) after multiple imputation. For instance, if I am imputing the variable "Cancer Stage" in my dataset, there may be [10 of Stage 1, 12 of Stage 2, 14 of Stage 3, 16 of Stage 4] in imputed set 1, and [11 of Stage 1, 11 of Stage 2, 13 of Stage 3, 17 of Stage 4] in imputed set 2, and so on and so forth.

I'm fully capable of extracting each imputed dataset and manually getting the counts and proportions in each dataset (in my case, I would use the complete() function in *mice* to extract each set as a dataframe and do the rest in Python). However, although I know that questions regarding descriptive statistics after multiple imputation have been asked previously, no confirmatory answer has been given. So, to reiterate, if I want to generate descriptive statistics (frequencies, proportions, and counts) of let's say, Cancer Stage, above, after multiple imputation, which of the following 3 might be the best approach?

1) Report the original dataset with counts of missing values?

2) Report the counts of just one of the imputed datasets, as I have seen in a paper?

3) Report "pooled" counts (i.e. average the counts of Cancer Stage across all the imputed datasets), then in an Appendix, also provide the original, non-imputed dataset with counts of missing values?

Option 3 seems to make the most sense to me, and is the most transparent, but I have not found any papers or official literature on whether this is theoretically appropriate.